# first time user logs in, upload images mkdir() work perfect but same user upload photos Warning: mkdir(): File exists?

Tags: php, html, mkdir, file-exists

I have a problem with `mkdir()` function.

In my website first time user can login add photos `mkdir()` working and same user second time upload images:

> Warning: mkdir(): File exists.

Message can display I will check all the formats in mkdir no one is working.

My code looks like:

```
$folder="users/$aid/projects/$prname/";
if(!file_exists($folder) && is_dir($folder)) {
    $path = mkdir("$folder/images", 0777, true);
}
```

Fist time user visit this page directory created but second time upload images it is not working above error will display.

Remain Content also not saved in database.

First time user can visit images folder created. Second time also user visit that page upload images problem is occurring.

Comment: Very hard to understand the problem.  Is `$aid` the same each time?  What about `$prname`? Why is `$folder` not fully qualified?

Comment: Also, your test does not make sense - if `$folder` does not exist, *and* it is a directory? When will this ever be true?

Comment: $aid is user id and $prname is project name   the out pt is like users/1/projects/MyHome/

Comment: so please give me solution  how to write if user enter here project images upload that folder only. mkdir()exists error message not came

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it as follows?
First we need to check if the folder exists.

```
$folder="users/$aid/projects/$prname/";
 if(!is_dir($folder))
   mkdir("$folder", 0777, true))

 if (!is_dir($folder."/images"))
   $path = mkdir("$folder/images", 0777, true);
```

Comment: still get same error Warning: mkdir(): File exists but images saved in directory

Comment: an extra ) . delete it

Comment: Also note that the third parameter of `mkdir()` if it should be done recursively, so you don't even have to check for the first case. Just check if the images folder exists, and if not, create it (recursively, including all parents).

Comment: only mkdir("$folder", 0777, true);